# NULL value of datatime datatype in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have table called `post_data` with 9 fields

```
username, email, pass, cam_name, upd_date(of type datetime) etc ...
```

I make `upd_date` field to NULL from auto updation of current data and time.

But the problem is, when I retrieve particular fields like `cam_name`, `cam_img` etc in another page with `rowCount` condition, it takes NULL as value. I want stop that..

Here is code to retrieve specified column from database

```
$stmt = $index_home->getDetails();

if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {        
       extract($row);
  }
}
```

`getDetails` implemtation:

```
public function getDetails() {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT userID, user_name, cam_name, cam_model, cam_rent, cam_img, mobile FROM post_data ORDER BY userID DESC');
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
        }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **[`PDO::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)** instead of `PDOStatement::rowCount()`

> For most databases, **PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the
>   number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use
>   PDO::query()** to issue a SELECT COUNT(*) statement with the same
>   predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use
>   PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will
>   be returned

Comment: Already emailid and user name , password fields are filled and another fields in that table are empty..and upd_date feilds having null value..but problem I when I retrieve that fields (can_name, can_IMG etc ) rowcount returns 1 ...but I want rowcount () must return 0 .                   In select query also I never select update_date field.

Comment: @lohithkumar A link is already mentioned, you will get the example there

Comment: bro.. i failed to understand... i just want to count only specific columns like "SELECT cam_name, cam_img COUNT(*) FROM post_data" is it possible or not?

Comment: `COUNT` doesn't work like that. Read here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp